# How to set a Flutter Custom Notification Icon ?,because there is no default notification icon in flutter for fcm

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, icons

I want to set a custom notification icon to appear in my notifications panel for my flutter app when i use fcm(firebase cloud messaging) but there is only a grey circle that appears and no icon .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After Searching for a long time i finally found the answer and here it is:

1. Create a custom notification icon using this [tool](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit).
2. Paste the generated list of icons in `android/app/src/main/res`.
3. Go to your manifest `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and add the following meta data in the **application** (not activity) tag:

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

4. If you don't have a colors.xml in res/values, create one:
   [image]
5. Done! It should work, let me know if it doesn't.

Discussion for the question [is here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17941#issuecomment-412242466).

Comment: Little sidenote: The tool (Notification icon generator) names the icons sometimes in a strange way. To make the above configuration work, you need to rename every icon to ic_notification before you copy the icons into the ```android/app/src/main/res``` folder. Second point, to make the color work, rename the ```colorAccent``` in the colors.xml to ```colorPrimary```. That't is!

Comment: I tried the same. but this didnt work.