# Flutter problem: On lock screen and background screen notification Icon showing grey

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

On lock scren and background Notification Icon is showing in grey,

[image]

[image]

I have added this
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Push Notifications: Icon not displaying in notification, white square shown instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/android-push-notifications-icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-sh)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the answers in these similar posts:

- [How to set a Flutter Custom Notification Icon ?,because there is no default notification icon in flutter for fcm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70649052/20447561)
- [Firebase Notification is grey flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54056825/20447561)
- [Firebase Notification icon is gray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70174537/20447561)